# Asp: Wrap image inside a Table

Tags: asp.net, html, marquee

what I'm trying to do is create a `marque` of images going up to down 
Here is my code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td style="table-layout:fixed;border-collapse:collapse;">
<marquee direction="down">
<table >
<tr>
<td>
<img src="../Advertise/Add1.jpg" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="../Advertise/Add2.jpg" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src="../Advertise/Add3.jpg" />
</td>
</tr>
</table></marquee>
<td/>
</tr>
</table>
Add1,Add2,Add3 are inside a folder
```

Now the problem is the size of the image was same as it is actually

### i want to wrap it according to the size of my `<td>`

please give me suggestions how to do it
thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saying the problem is that the image is displaying at the size of itself?  That is a good thing.  If you want to explicitly set the size of all the images you have to either set them in your markup or write javascript/jquery to edit their size after being loaded.  To make them keep HxW ratio you can do a % based on the dimension that needs to shrink the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set height and width to 100% as mentioned below :

```
<img src="../Advertise/Add1.jpg" style="height:100%;width:100%" />
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td style="table-layout: fixed; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <marquee direction="down">
                <table>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="../Advertise/Add1.jpg" style="height: 100%;width: 100%" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="../Advertise/Add2.jpg" style="height: 100%;width: 100%" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                <img src="../Advertise/Add3.jpg" style="height: 100%;width: 100%" />
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
            </marquee>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```